# file.exists() returning false even if Uri exists hence not able to delete file

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, android-11

I am not able to delete files from the device. I am getting the file right but when calling `file.exists()` it returns false. This is how I create the file.

```
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

When printing URI it shows -
`/external_files/Android/data/com.akshit.akshitsfdc.allpuranasinhindi/files/puran_collection/filename.pdf`

```
 if(uri == null){
        Log.d("FileUtils", "deleteFileFromUri: null uri");
        return false;
    }
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    Log.d("FileUtils", "deleteFileFromUri: file : "+file+" : "+file.exists());

    if(file != null){
        try{
           return file.delete();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
    Log.d("FileUtils", "deleteFileFromUri: file does not exists : "+uri.getPath());
```

Comment: What is exact error/exception message? Do you get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> Permission is added. I am not getting any exception, I am just getting  file.exists() false

Comment: please post your log.

Comment: Should I post complete log?

Comment: int result = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null); is answer to my question!